# Understanding Haskell's type system

Tags: haskell

I've got three functions

```
boombangs xs = [if x < 10 then "BOOM" else "BANG" | x <- xs odd x]

length' xs = sum [1 | _ <- xs]

removeNonUppercase st = [x | x <- st, x `elem` ['A'..'Z']]
```

Here's what I get for the type(type signature?) of each function

```
*Main> :t boombangs
boombangs :: Integral a => [a] -> [[Char]]
*Main> :t length'
length' :: Num a => [t] -> a
*Main> :t removeNonUppercase 
removeNonUppercase :: [Char] -> [Char]
```

Haskell should give me an error when I pass an array of ints to removeNonUppercase or a string to boombangs. It does too, but how does it know it's wrong when I haven't specified the type anywhere.

Also why are the types of boombangs and removeNonUppercase different even though they work on the same input.

I apologize if the question seems vague or downright ignorant. I've just started on Learn You a Haskell and I'm slowly wrapping my head around this paradigm coming from programming mainly in C and python.

Any resources for learning more about haskell and the type system would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC uses type inference to try to guess what type your function can be.

In `boombangs`, it can tell that you're passing in a list because of the `x <- xs` in the list comprehension, and it can tell that the list elements must have type `Integral a => a` because you're applying `odd` to each element.  It knows you're returning a list of `String`s because of the literal `"BOOM"` and `"BANG"` inside the list comprehension.

In `length'`, your type is only constrained by `sum`, which requires `Num a => [a]`.  Your input type is a list of any type because you don't actually perform any operations on the elements themselves, but you do indicate that the parameter is a list by the `_ <- xs`.

In `removeNonUpperCase`, it sees that you're passing in a list for the same reasons as the first two functions, and since you're checking if each element is in the list `['A'..'Z']`, so each element must be a `Char`, so you're taking a list of `Char`s and returning a list of `Char`s, since no other transformation is performed on the elements.  Since `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`, it knows the type fully.

Comment: It's kinda fascinating how that works to me. As a follow up, would you be able to tell me why the type of length is `length :: [a] -> Int` while my length' has the longer `length' :: Num a => [t] -> a`. I think your answer suggests that my length' has the `Num a` bit because of the sum function. How does the built-in length differ from this. Can it operate on types that my function cannot?

Comment: The built in `length` function has its type signature provided, and it is more efficient to use `Int` instead of `Integer`, `Float`, or `Double`.  The built in definition is different than your definition as well, but it still is essentially based on `+`.  The type of `+` is `Num a => a -> a -> a`, since we want that operator to work with all numbers, not just `Int`.  The only real difference between the type signatures is that the built-in uses a concrete instance of `Num`, while yours is more general.  In practice, having it more general is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

> how does it know it's wrong when I haven't specified the type anywhere.

Haskell compiler, GHC in your case, can do type inference, which means it can figure out (almost always) what the type of an expression by context information. For example, for

```
mbangs xs = [if x < 10 then "BOOM" else "BANG" | x <- xs, odd x]
```

you could infer its type manually like this:

1. You define `mbangs` by list comprehension, so `xs` must be a list, and
2. you apply `odd` on the element of `xs`, therefore the type of `xs` must be `(Integral a) => [a]`, because the type of `odd` is `(Integral a) => a -> Bool`.
3. Also, for each element of `xs`, you generate a `String` by your output function `if x < 10 then "BOOM" else "BANG"`,
4. therefore the type of `mbangs` must be `Integral a => [a] -> [[Char]]`, as `ghci` just told you.

> why are the types of boombangs and removeNonUppercase different even though they work on the same input.

Because you are using different output function in their list comprehension definitions.

Comment: So, the type of a function includes both its input(s) and its output(s). Is the output the bit that comes after `->` in the type?

Answer (score 0):

For `boombangs`, it can see by the operators you apply to x that it can't be a string.  For `removeNonUpperCase`, it can see that the elements have to be in `['A'..'Z']`, and so can't be ints.  Which also explains why they DON'T work on the same input.